# How to send login and password to a server using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, asihttprequest, httprequest

I'm pretty new to everything that deals with http and stuff like that and i know almost nothing about how http methods work so i need your advice. In my app i have to send login and password to a server and get a response. By now i'm trying to write a method (it's called STUB in English i believe) which will work in a general way without communicating to actual server. Should i use POST method in a manner similar to:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:some_server_url];
[request addPostValue:passwordString forKey:loginString];
```

or something else? if first how do i receive the response from the server? Could you please show me few lines of code?

Comment: Just came to this post for an answer..and was wondering if you are  encrypting the password and then sending it or just sending the plain password..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass login details to  server using HTTP POST method like this :

```
-(NSDictionary*)userLogIn:(NSMutableDictionary*)inputDictionary{


    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSString *convertedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@",username, password];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Give the url here"]];     
    [request setHTTPBody:[convertedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"XXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"USER_AGENT"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];    

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];   
    [parser release];

    [json_string release];  

    return statuses;


}
```

This is a sample code and you have to change according to your requirements.